# Incompatible types: android.widget.Edit Text and java.lang.String

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have got this error on Android Studio IDE. It says

> Incompatible types; Required android.widget.EditText and Found java.lang.String

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    if (editabletext.length() == 8) {
        editabletext = editabletext.getText().toString().replaceAll("([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})", "$1-$2")
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your editabletext? An EditText?

Comment: So sorry I forgot to mention that part, editabletext is an EditText not a String

Comment: it should be `editabletext.setText() = editabletext.getText().toString().replaceAll("([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})", "$1-$2")`..dont know what your purpose is..

Comment: What you probably want to do is `s = editabletext.getText().toString().replaceAll("([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})", "$1-$2");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`editabletext` is an EditText and `replaceAll` returns a String. What the compiler says is that you can't assign a `String` to an `EditText`. You could change your code this way:

```
if(editabletext.length() == 8){
    String tmp = editabletext.getText().toString().replaceAll("([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})", "$1-$2");
    editabletext.setText(tmp);
  }
```

Comment: How would I go about fixing this issue do you know ?

Comment: I already posted a possible solution to your issue. You could assign the returned value of replaceAll to String and then use setText on the EditText

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
editabletext= editabletext.getText().toString().replaceAll("([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})", "$1-$2")
```

with

```
editabletext.setText(editabletext.getText().toString().replaceAll("([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})", "$1-$2"))
```

as `editabletext` is of type `Editable` and `replaceAll` returns a `String`

Answer (score -1):

find the definition of "editabletext" and change the type from EditText to String

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please provide the complete answer if you wish to helo others and also refer to the deomunentation or links where we can find *the definition* and also please complete your answer.