# Incompatible types.Edit text error in android

Tags: java, android

I get this error saying it is required EditText. but found java.lang.String.

I have already defined the EditText. can anyone please let me know what i'm doing is wrong? I'm not sure its in the code so i even did a clean, but it is still not working. so i think in the code i have done something wrong.

```
public class Admin_update extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText txsearch,txname,txprice,txinfo, txcategory;
Button btnUpdate;
String SearchName;

FlowerDbHelper flowerDbHelper;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_update);

    txsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txSearch);
    txname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txName);
    txprice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txPrice);
    txinfo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txInfo);
    txcategory = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txCategory);

    btnUpdate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

    txname.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    txprice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    txinfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    txcategory.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    btnUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}

public void btnSearch(View view){
SearchName = txsearch.getText().toString();
   flowerDbHelper = new FlowerDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
   sqLiteDatabase = flowerDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = flowerDbHelper.getFlower(SearchName,sqLiteDatabase);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        txprice = cursor.getString(0); <--- ERROR IS HERE...




    }


}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incompatible types: android.widget.Edit Text and java.lang.String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052935/incompatible-types-android-widget-edit-text-and-java-lang-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign a `String` to an `EditText`.  The variable types aren't the same.  If you want to display a string in an `EditText`, you use `editText.setText(text_to_set)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

`txprice.setText(cursor.getString(0));`

Have a nice day